# javascript function for select box not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Dear all i m a new bie

the scenario is filling a select box based on the selection of the first select box below is my code

this part of code fills first select box from mysql and when i select a value from the select box the jquery function isnt triggered nothing happens with the second select box

```
<?php require_once("db_connect.php");?>
<?php require_once("functions.php");?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".brands").change(function()
     {
    var id=$(this).val();
   var dataString = 'id='+ id;

 $.ajax
 ({
 type: "POST",
 url: "array_types.php",
 data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success: function(html)
   {
       $(".type").html(html);
   }
 });

 });

  });
 </script>
 <?php
 echo "Country :
<select name=\"brands\" class=\"brands\">";
    $brand_set=get_brands();
 while($brand=mysqli_fetch_assoc($brand_set)){
    echo "<option value=".$brand['brand_id'].">".$brand['brand_name']."</option>";
 }
echo "</select> <br/><br/>
    City :
<select name=\"type\" class=\"type\">
<option selected=\"selected\">--Select Type--</option>
</select>";
       ?>
```

and this is my array_types.php

```
     <?php require_once("db_connect.php");?>
     <?php require_once("functions.php");?>
     <?php

     if($_POST['id'])
      {
      $id=$_POST['id'];
     $type_set=get_type_details($id);
while($type=mysqli_fetch_assoc($type_set)){
echo "<option value=".$type['prodtype_id'].">".$type['prod_type']."</option>";
}
     }?>
```

the functions.php is basically retireving records from the mysql DB 
please help me why the second select box isnt getting filled

regards

Koder

Comment: Put the file jquery-1.10.2.js in same directory where the coded file exits then try it

Comment: Its in the same directory

Comment: what you get when alert `html` from ajax response?

Comment: just console.log(html) see what you get ????????

Comment: <select class="type" name="type">
<option selected="selected">--Select Type--</option>
</select> just this

Answer (score 0):

gotcha!
on LINE 8  var dataString = 'id='+ id; i shall have to pass brand_id instead of id